# Pytest how to enforce test collection in subfolder containing pytest.ini

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Let's say I have the following folder structure:

```
MyPackage
- subfolder
-- pytest.ini
-- my_module.py
-- test_module.py
```

The `pytest.ini` in `subfolder` contains this:

```
[pytest]
python_files = test_*.py my_module*.py
```

The `my_module.py` contains test functions like `def test_this()`.
If I call pytest to collect tests in the `subfolder`, It collects the tests in `my_module.py` as well, as expected:

```sh
pytest --collect-only MyPackage/subfolder
```

However, if I call pytest for MyPackage, it does not collect the tests in `my_module.py`, only in `test_module.py`

```sh
pytest --collect-only MyPackage
```

My question is: Can it be done so that pytest recursively processes the `pytest.ini` in the subfolder?

In other words: What is the scope of the pytest.ini files in the subfolders? Is ot only processed if pytest is called locally? Is there a way to force pytest to recursively process pytest.ini in subfolders?

Comment: specify the `rootdir` https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/customize.html#initialization-determining-rootdir-and-configfile

Comment: What do you mean? like this? ```pytest --rootdir=subfolder .```?

Comment: It will still use the pytest.ini in the MyPackage folder. And what I would like to achieve is to be able to use pytest.ini files in the subfolders, so that they are recursively parsed, I'm just not sure, if it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that it cannot be done: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7732

However, there is a workaround. I managed to do this as follows, inside the `conftest.py` in my package root:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from pytest import Module

package_loc = Path(__file__).parent

additional_modules = [
    package_loc / "subfolder" / "my_module.py",
]


def pytest_collect_file(path, parent):
    if Path(path) in additional_modules:
        return Module.from_parent(fspath=path, parent=parent)
    else:
        return None
```